# django переход на разные страницы

Tags: python, django

пишу свой сайт на django, пока что там есть 3 страницы: главная, регистрация и авторизация. заметила, что при переходе со страницы регистрации на страницу авторизации, url-адрес не обновляется, а складывается с предыдущим. т.е., url-адрес регистрации: registration/ и когда я перехожу на страницу авторизации, я хочу заменить этот адрес другим: login/ но вместо этого они складываются и я, естественно, получаю ошибку о несуществующем адресе. то же самое происходит и когда я перехожу наоборот со страницы авторизации на страницу регистрации. как решить проблему?

urls.py самого приложения:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("<int:advertisement_id>/", advertisement, name="advertisement"),
    path("new/<int:advertisement_id>", make_advertisement_id, name="new_advertisement"),
    path('registration/', RegistrationUserView.as_view(), name='registration'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login')
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py проекта:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("apartment_app.urls")),
]
```

Comment: Значит у вас в шаблоне неправильные ссылки прописаны, urls.py тут ни при чём

Answer (score 0):

разобралась, в html шаблоне поставила

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}"..>
```

для кнопки войти и

```
<a href="{% url 'registration' %}"..>
```

для кнопки регистрации, теперь все работает